Some functions are not executing when calling the onClick of my Button widget
I use the Room Library to save data
I want that before saving the data proceed to the assignment of values to 2 fields of my table.
Thus only the last assignment is executed when I consult my database. But when I hide the last one I see that the first assignment works.
So I do not understand why this is not working correctly
The code of my Button
Button(
        onClick = {
onItemValueChange(itemUiState.itemDetails.copy(orange_money = itemUiState.itemDetails.vente_om))
onItemValueChange(itemUiState.itemDetails.copy(caisse = itemUiState.itemDetails.vente_om))
            onSaveClick()
                  },
        enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
Text(stringResource(R.string.save_action))
    }

I even tried to put my value assignments in the run but the same result (only the second assignment is saved in the database)
Button (
     onClick = {
          run{
onItemValueChange(itemUiState.itemDetails.copy(orange_money = itemUiState.itemDetails.vente_om))
onItemValueChange(itemUiState.itemDetails.copy(caisse = itemUiState.itemDetails.vente_om))
          }
          onSaveClick()
     },
     enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
     shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ){
Text(stringResource(R.string.save_action))
    }

